# How to hide nevigation bar when a guest user visit the site member profile

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to hide navigation menu's when any guest user visit the site member's profile(user's public pages).
[image]

Comment: Is this profile page is custom page in your site ?

Comment: @Haris Nope not custom page.

Answer (score 0):

In the theme you can hide or show the navigation bar. You can put up the condition and check if the user is on  site member's profile(user's public pages) in portal_normal.ftl file.

```
<#if has_navigation || is_signed_in>
    <#include "${full_templates_path}/navigation.ftl" />
</#if>
```

Comment: my question is not for loggedin user, look at image! ITs for any visitor if he visit to member profile the menu item should be disappear

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this:

```
#if(!($themeDisplay.getLayout().isPublicLayout() && $themeDisplay.getLayout().getFriendlyURL().equals("/profile")))
    <!--show the menu items-->
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

A user's public pages by default are visible to everybody.

Do you want the content on the other pages to not be available, then use permissions on the pages, or use private pages.

Do you just want the navigation bar to disappear, while the pages would be available to the users knowing the URLs (or through alternative navigation), you can apply Danish's solution easiest by having a specific theme for users' personal sites.

Comment: as per danish's solution, it will disappear the navigation if the user get signIn. what i want is: Please visit 'www.liferay.com' without getting signin and you can see the multiple menu's on navigation bar "like:- Products, for businees, developer, AboutUS". Now visit the anyone's profile without getting loggedin. (i.e http://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/profile), you can see the navigation item get disappear.